# How do I implement this type of dynamic UI in a Razor view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor-2

[image]

I will start by saying that I am an absolute newbie to web development and to MVC as well.

I want to implement a view for a Subscriber page (part of an MVC4 application dealing with Email marketing). What I want to implement is:

1) When the user clicks the "+ Add a List" button, a new Category should appear on the left and the cursor should blink, meaning it should be ready to receive the name for the category from the user. I also want that whenever the user hovers over any category name on the left, a small bar containing two buttons (edit and delete) should appear which should let the user edit the category name or delete that category. The thing I want is that all of these must happen without reloading the page.

2) When the user clicks the "+ Add Contact" button, a pop up dialog box containing two tabs should appear which lets the user either manually enter the details or upload a CSV to capture the details. Whenever the user clicks the "Add Contact" button or "Upload and Add Contacts" in the pop up dialog box, I want the new contacts to display in the contact list region shown in the picture (once again, without reloading the page). I also want the same hover bar for the contacts too (same as categories).

[image]

I am confused as to how to implement this in a Razor view? What do I use - JavaScript/jQuery/AJAX?

I am pretty much lost. Can someone please guide me a little bit so that I can continue and finish my first MVC4 project?

Comment: Did you walked through the MVC tutorial on asp.net site?

Comment: Not completely. As I have very little time for research and learning. This is a school project, I am in absolute hurry. I understand my approach is wrong and MVC has a learning curve, but I am like *start the development and we will see what comes along the way*. Hope you understand.

Answer (score 0):

You need some javascript libraries like jQuery UI or maybe Kendo UI, I'd recommend to use jQuery UI at this time. they have many widgets but look at these. and keep in mind that a cshtml view can be look upon like a html page, you can have all tags, css and javascript you want there:

http://jqueryui.com/dialog/

http://jqueryui.com/tabs/

http://jqueryui.com/